# a counter example for 2nd derivative

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

The answer is A. I can't think of a counter example for 2nd derivative for B. It could be that the 2nd derivative doesn't exist. But what if it does? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Well, intuitively, if $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ is finite, that is $<\infty$, it kinda should approach a constant, right? For example something like $f(x) = e^{-x}+C$... So the derivatives should approach $0$ ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Function which approaches $0$ for large $x$:
$$\frac{\sin(x^2)}{x^2}$$
Derivative approaches $0$:
$$(2 x^2 \cos(x^2) - 2\sin(x^2))/x^3$$
Second derivative does not approach $0$:
$$\frac{-6\cos(x^2)}{x^2} + \frac{6}{x^4}\sin(x^2) -4 \sin(x^2)$$